# How to forbid a google api infoWindow to open at page loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I found this script.

It allows to create a info window with google api. I modified it to fit my needs but I can't forbid it to open all infowindows automatically when I load the page (I only want a single info window appears when the costumers click on the marker).

Someone can help me?

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();



/* An InfoBox is like an info window, but it displays
 * under the marker, opens quicker, and has flexible styling.
 * @param {GLatLng} latlng Point to place bar at
 * @param {Map} map The map on which to display this InfoBox.
 * @param {Object} opts Passes configuration options - content,
 *   offsetVertical, offsetHorizontal, className, height, width
 */
function InfoBox(opts) {
  google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
  this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
  this.map_ = opts.map;
  this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
  this.offsetHorizontal_ = 0;
  this.height_ = 165;
  this.width_ = 266;

  var me = this;
  this.boundsChangedListener_ =
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function() {
      return me.panMap.apply(me);
    });

  // Once the properties of this OverlayView are initialized, set its map so
  // that we can display it.  This will trigger calls to panes_changed and
  // draw.
  this.setMap(this.map_);
}

/* InfoBox extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API
 */
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox
 */
InfoBox.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

/* Redraw the Bar based on the current projection and zoom level
 */
InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Creates the element if it doesn't exist already.
  this.createElement();
  if (!this.div_) return;

  // Calculate the DIV coordinates of two opposite corners of our bounds to
  // get the size and position of our Bar
  var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (!pixPosition) return;

  // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
  this.div_.style.width = "389px";
  this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.height = "135px";
  this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox in the floatPane.  If the panes
 * object, retrieved by calling getPanes, is null, remove the element from the
 * DOM.  If the div exists, but its parent is not the floatPane, move the div
 * to the new pane.
 * Called from within draw.  Alternatively, this can be called specifically on
 * a panes_changed event.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function() {
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // This does not handle changing panes.  You can set the map to be null and
    // then reset the map to move the div.
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "1px solid #CCC";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.background = "url('img/proj_box.png')";  //389 × 135
    div.style.width = "389px";
    div.style.height = "135px";
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
    contentDiv.style.padding = "30px"
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "<b><a href=\"projets.php\">Hello World!</a></b>";

    var topDiv = document.createElement("div");
    topDiv.style.textAlign = "right";
    var closeImg = document.createElement("img");
    closeImg.style.width = "32px";
    closeImg.style.height = "32px";
    closeImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
    closeImg.src = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/closebigger.gif";
    topDiv.appendChild(closeImg);

    function removeInfoBox(ib) {
      return function() {
        ib.setMap(null);
      };
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));

    div.appendChild(topDiv);
    div.appendChild(contentDiv);
    div.style.display = 'none';
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    this.panMap();
  } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {
    // The panes have changed.  Move the div.
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
  } else {
    // The panes have not changed, so no need to create or move the div.
  }
}

/* Pan the map to fit the InfoBox.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.panMap = function() {
  // if we go beyond map, pan map
  var map = this.map_;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  if (!bounds) return;

  // The position of the infowindow
  var position = this.latlng_;

  // The dimension of the infowindow
  var iwWidth = this.width_;
  var iwHeight = this.height_;

  // The offset position of the infowindow
  var iwOffsetX = this.offsetHorizontal_;
  var iwOffsetY = this.offsetVertical_;

  // Padding on the infowindow
  var padX = 40;
  var padY = 40;

  // The degrees per pixel
  var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
  var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
  var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
  var boundsSpan = bounds.toSpan();
  var longSpan = boundsSpan.lng();
  var latSpan = boundsSpan.lat();
  var degPixelX = longSpan / mapWidth;
  var degPixelY = latSpan / mapHeight;

  // The bounds of the map
  var mapWestLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var mapEastLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var mapNorthLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var mapSouthLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();


  // Remove the listener after panning is complete.
  google.maps.event.removeListener(this.boundsChangedListener_);
  this.boundsChangedListener_ = null;
};


function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    //scrollwheel: false,
    //navigationControl: false,
    //mapTypeControl: false,
    //scaleControl: false,
    //draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }

    , function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Try Google Gears Geolocation



    //AJOUT MARKERS






// Create a base icon for all of our markers that specifies the
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48,2);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"Hello World!"
  });  


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");


  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8,2);

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2, 
      map: map, 
      title:"Hello World!"
  });  


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(e) {
      var infoBox2 = new InfoBox({latlng: marker2.getPosition(), map: map});
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker2, "click");




  }



}








</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your initialize function:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");

google.maps.event.trigger(marker2, "click");
```